# How widely is Apple Pay supported in Japan?

Tags: japan, payment

I'm going on a trip to Japan soon and the announcement that as of iOS 10.x there's support for Apple Pay in the country is great news!

However, I also understand that a lot of the NFC / contactless payment technology there is based on the Felica standard / Suica cards hence the question: how widely supported is Apple Pay in Japan?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/77755/108

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note: I am an Android user so this is not first-hand knowledge.*

Per [Apple's Japanese Apple Pay page](https://www.apple.com/jp/apple-pay/), Apple Pay can be used at all stores where Suica can be used, which is virtually all stores that accept contactless payments in the first place (*i.e.*, you are extremely unlikely to encounter a store that displays one of the other four logos but not the Suica one; the only one I know is [my local pharmacy](https://store.aisei.co.jp/detail/365)). For reference, however, the five logos to look for are the following:

[image]

In order to use the Suica payment feature, you need to install the Suica app and set it up as described [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207155). Note that only iPhone 8 and above (as well as iPhone 7/7+ sold in Japan) can be used to pay in stores. For Apple Watch owners, Series 3 and Japan-sold Series 2 can be used as well.

Comment: Is this true for international iPhones with Apple Pay as well? The one which doesn't have the Felica module present in the Japanese version.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee Depends on the iPhone model; see edit.

Comment: I am afraid it's more complicated than that. Even the iPhone has the FeliCa secure element at manufacture, it could still be disabled by iOS by geo-blocking. On the other hand, LAWSON, the convenient store, [has remarked that "Overseas Apple Pay device is not available"](http://www.lawson.co.jp/service/payment/settlement/).

Comment: @KH.Lee I do not have a recent iPhone but it seems you just need to changeyour "Region" setting to "Japan"...

Comment: The reason for this is, originally only iPhones made for the Japanese market had the FeliCa + RFD chipset ( iPhone 7 and up ). When they say Apple pay on the Apple website, they're talking about the iPhones in Japan. I don't know if this also applies for recent iPhones but it would appear that iPhone 8 and up have both RFD and Felica worldwide.